# Special characters on attributes of an Enum

Tags: java, typescript

I have two Enums, one on java

```js
private enum MyEnum{
     enum1,
     enum2,
     enum3;


 public String traduction() {
        return Messages.get(this.toString());
    }

}
```

And the same one on typeScript

```js
import {Enum} from "../../enum";

export class MyEnum extends Enum {

    static enum1 = new MyEnum('enum1');
    static enum2 = new MyEnum('enum2');
    static enum3 = new MyEnum('enum3');

}
```

I need to add special characters on elements in my Enums, in order to display something like this :

enum(1) 
enum(2) 
enum3

How can I do that in JAVA and typescript?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your `MyEnum` as follows:

```
private enum MyEnum {
     enum1("enum(1)"),
     enum2("enum(2)"),
     enum3("enum3");

 String description;

 public String toString() {
      return this.description;
 }

 public MyEnum(String description) {
     this.description = description;
 }

 public String traduction() {
        return Messages.get(this.toString());
    }

}
```

OR

```
private enum MyEnum {
     enum1("enum(1)"),
     enum2("enum(2)"),
     enum3;

 String description;

 public String toString() {
      return this.description;
 }

 public MyEnum(String description) {
     this.description = description;
 }

 public MyEnum() {
     this.description = super.toString();
 }

 public String traduction() {
        return Messages.get(this.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that OP changed the question; edit just brings it inline.

Comment: Thanks, that work for me :) Do you have any idea how can I do that on typescript ?

Comment: typescript ... no idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer for Typescript, but in Java you can simply override the `toString()` method, e.g.

```
enum MyEnum {
  enum1, enum2, enum3;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return super.toString().replaceAll("(.*)(\\d+)", "$1($2)");
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/81hbVi)

Comment: Thank you! But I don't need to do that for all attributes

Comment: This answers your question as it was when I wrote it. If you need to do something different for different values, @Azodious' approach would be easiest.